# mutate variable by condition using two variables in long format data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table, long-format-data

In this data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), time=rep(1:3,2), x=c(1,0,0,0,1,0))
dt
   id time x
1:  1    1 1
2:  1    2 0
3:  1    3 0
4:  2    1 0
5:  2    2 1
6:  2    3 0
```

I need the following:

```
   id time x
1:  1    1 1
2:  1    2 1
3:  1    3 1
4:  2    1 0
5:  2    2 1
6:  2    3 1
```

that is

1. if `x==1` at `time==1` then `x=1` at times 2 and 3, by `id`
2. if `x==1` at `time==2` then `x=1` at time 3, by `id`

For the first point (I guess the second one will be similar), I have tried approaches mentioned in similar questions I posted before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67373253/fill-variable-cells-by-id-in-long-format-data-table-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004330/condition-on-multiple-rows-and-multiple-columns-by-id-in-r-long-format-table)), but none work:

- `dt[x==1[time == 1],  x := x[time == 1], id]` gives an error
- `setDT(dt)[, x2:= ifelse(x==1 & time==1, x[time==1], x), by=id]` changes `x`only at `time 1` (so, no real change observed)

It would be much easier to work with data.table in wide format, but I keep facing this kind of problem in long format and I don't want to reshape my data all the time

Thank you!

EDIT:

The answer provided by @GregorThomas, `dt[, x := cummax(x), by = id]`, works for the problem that I presented.

Now I ask the same question for a character variable:

```
dt2 <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), time=rep(1:3,2), x=c('a','b','b','b','a','b'))
dt2
   id time x
1:  1    1 a
2:  1    2 b
3:  1    3 b
4:  2    1 b
5:  2    2 a
6:  2    3 b
```

In the table above, how could be done the following:

1. if `x=='a'` at `time==1` then `x='a'` at times 2 and 3, by id
2. if `x=='a'` at `time==2` then `x='a'` at time 3, by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the cumulative maximum function `cummax`:

```
dt[, x := cummax(x), by = id]
dt
# id time x
# 1:  1    1 1
# 2:  1    2 1
# 3:  1    3 1
# 4:  2    1 0
# 5:  2    2 1
# 6:  2    3 1
```

Comment: Thank you, @GregorThomas and @GuedesBF, this works! But if `x` was a character, this option would not be possible.  Do you not what could work in that case?

Comment: You provided example data with a numeric column. Please edit your question to include a reprex for text data

Comment: In other situations I'd probably use `cumsum` to trigger a condition, something like `x := fifelse(cumsum(x == "A") > 1, "A", x))`. Trying to generalize a bit...